# What is causing wildly differing DL/UL speeds from open speedtest

Tags: download-speed

As explained by the title, I get results such as **DL:245 UL:4828** attached screenshot.

Can someone help me to understand why?
[image]

Comment: Which OS? What version? Which browser? WiFi or Ethernet? Please add all these information in your question.

Comment: Try to take the test here. https://www.speedtest.net/ @J. scorned

Comment: Ubuntu based pop-os, brave, Ethernet.

Comment: Speedtest does give 236 DL and 36 UL, but I wish to use openspeedtest chrome extension and have consistently gotten these diverse results on both wifi as well as eth and want to understand why this may be.. TIA for the collective cycles

Comment: Unfortunately Pop_OS is off-topic here.